# Does paint only apply to certain types of blocks?

Tags: terraria-mobile

When I bought paint from the painter I tried to paint wood, stone, dirt, and multiple other blocks with paintbrush. Why isn't paint working? Does it only work on certain blocks or items?

Comment: Did you buy the 3 painting tools?

Comment: Yes I did.,,,,,

Comment: I suggest you try to describe how the paint "isn't working". Is it consumed? Are you using the right tool for the right surface? Does anything happen at all when you swing the brush?

Comment: Yes it is consumed, yes I'm using the right tool, and no, nothing happens at all.

Answer (score 3):

You can't paint some blocks with standard paint (eg. Gray brick, Glass blocks...), if you apply the paint of these blocks, nothing will happen even though the paint will be removed from your inventory.

To paint them you'll have to use their **Deep** version which you can acquire by combining two standard paint at the [**Dye Vat**](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Dye_Vat) that you can buy from the **Dye Trader** for 5 gold.

For example, if you want to paint a Gray Brick in red, you'll have to buy two **Red Paint** and craft them into one **Deep Red Paint** at the **Dye Vat**.

You can paint almost all blocks in Terraria, even trees or furnitures. Just give it a try with standard paint and deep paint! And remember to use the **Paint Roller** to paint walls and the **Paintbrush** to paint blocks.

Comment: Will wood need a deep color?

Comment: @Kitkat3547 I don't know, Terraria is not installed on my computer at the moment. Guess you'll have to try both! Fortunately, the paint is not very expensive.

Comment: I'm on mobile--

Comment: @Kitkat3547 Mobile or computer, there should be no difference in painting (apart from the Brown, Shadow and Negative paint available only on the computer version).